# SELECT com o Total de um Pedido que Contenha um Determinado Produto

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, select

Eu tenho 3 tabelas:

- uma de pedidos;
- uma de produtos;
- e uma de pedidos_produtos

Preciso fazer um `SELECT` que me retorne a soma dos pedidos que contenham um produto X, até agora fiz um `SELECT` assim:

```
SELECT
    pedido_id,
    SUM(valor_total),
FROM
    pedidos_produtos
GROUP BY
    pedido_id
ORDER BY
    pedido_id DESC
```

Quando faço um `HAVING` ou `WHERE` para filtrar os pedidos com o produto, ele me retorna só a soma daquele produto e eu preciso do total do pedido em si. Já tentei de várias formas, mas acho que minha lógica não está certa.

Comment: pesquisa pelo `EXISTS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando um *Case* dentro da função *Count* para obter a quantidade de linhas com esse determinado produto no pedido:

```
HAVING
    COUNT(CASE WHEN produto_id = 123 THEN 1 END) > 0
```

Espero que ajude